# Proxmox создать ВМ с OS

Tags: http, post, proxmox

Стоит задача создать виртуальную машину с операционной системой при помощи http запроса. 
Это вообще возможно? Если да то как? 
При создании виртуальной машины:
POST /api2/json/nodes/{node}/qemu
появляется новая машина, но она, как вы догадываетесь, абсолютно пуста. 
Среди параметров запроса нашел тип операционной системы, но не нашел ничего больше. Возможно не достаточно внимательно изучал. 
Возможно ли это и если ответ положительный то каким образом?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел два варианта решения данной задачи. 
Создаем ВМ -> устанавливаем и настраиваем OS -> готовую ВМ можно либо сделать шаблоном и из нее разворачивать новые ВМ, уже настроенные. Далее соответственно можно изменить любые параметры ВМ, единственное невозможно виртуальный диск сделать меньше чем он был, но можно увеличить. Либо второй вариант: начало такое же, на этапе машина готова и работает просто клонившем ее. С этой схемой у меня иногда возникают сложности. В частности машина - источник самопроизвольно выключается а сервер пишет, что не может завершить операцию. Повторяется не на всех ВМ. Но где повторяется работает первый вариант.